How to create a table with only indexes and no actual data?
Question: Is is possible to create a table in PostgreSQL for the sole purpose of creating specialized indexes (used for advanced search use-cases), without storing duplicate data in such tables?
Context: I have a table with a JSONB column that can contain dynamic (and nested keys). I've managed to create a function, called jsonb_flatten which can convert {a: {b: "val"}} to {"a.b": "val"}. However, I need trigram indexes on all possible values, which is not support by regular JSONB indexes, i.e. GIST/GIN. One solution could be to duplicate this data into a table with two fields key | value | original_row_id  and create a trigram index on the value column, but that would end-up unnecessarily duplicating the data. Thus, my question.

"sole purpose of creating specialized indexes...without storing duplicate data" - That is the purpose of clustering and clustered indexes. It organizes the actual data in the table itself without making a copy of it. But since it's only possible to sort data one specific way at a time, there can only be one clustered index / one way to cluster a table. Any other simultaneous sortings of the data would only be possible with a copy of said data (aka nonclustered indexes).

@J.D.not sure if table clustering is the solution in this case. As per my understanding of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html it physically reorders data in a table according to an index, such that requesting ranges / clusters of rows dependent on that index  becomes more efficient. That's not my use-case. My use-case is basically how to create trigram indexes on all the values of a dynamic JSON without data duplication.

My point is, all indexes create a duplicate of the data except the clustered index. There's no way around that.

No, that is not possible. You may have to choose a different data model without JSON.

@J.D. I think you are using terminology form MSSQL or Mysql.  In Oracle, what you describe is called an Index-organized-table.  In PostgreSQL, that feature is not implemented at all, and the word "clustered" is used to mean something else.

@jjanes The ideology is the same and not unique to any particular database system. PostgreSQL docs.

@J.D. As the page you link to makes clear, they are not the same "ideology".  Just the same word, used to mean different things.  In PostgreSQL, all indexes are secondary indexes, even the ones used to back a primary key constraint.

@jjanes That's fine, but PostgreSQL's implementation of clustering is still ~90% the same. As the docs say, "When a table is clustered, it is physically reordered based on the index information..." - This is what happens in other database system's implementations as well. The main difference being the clustered index is the table itself, not a copy of the data, and typically is continually maintained without having to manually re-cluster. To say "that feature is not implemented at all" is further from true than to say they are the same.

@J.D. Clustering in Postgres still keeping the data in heap , ordered based on a secondary index. While MSSQL's clustered index do this in the same B-tree itself with leafs containing actual data not pointer?

You can create a functional index.  The index itself will contain the data it needs to of course, but there won't be an extra copy of it in the table.
create index on j using gin (flatten_to_text(jsonb) gin_trgm_ops);

select * from j where flatten_to_text(jsonb) like '%dog%'

Your flatten_to_text function must be immutable for this to work.

what would flatten_to_text return for a nested json? and how would I use it to do a fuzzy search on a particular field within the json?

I don't know, your problem specification isn't very clear.  It needs to return whatever it needs to return to make it do what you want.  Maybe just 'val'?
